# Java game can only loads images in eclipse

Tags: java, bufferedimage, 2d-games, game-development

I am new to game dev and I am currently making a simple java game from scratch. Everything is built in eclipse neon 3.0 and the game works well in it. However when I export the java project to an executable jar file , whenever it loads the images from the res file in .jar, it just crushes and gives no response. I am sure it is the problem of image loading since drawRect() still works fine.

This is how I load images in the game

```
//in my ImageLoader class 

public static BufferedImage load(String path){
try{
            return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
    }catch(IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in my asset class I declare variables for every images that would be used

```
public static BufferedImage mobs = 
ImageLoader.load(/texture/mobs.png);
```

and draw image in other classes by

```
g.drawImage(Asset.mobs , ...)
```

All png files are put in texture file under res file which is at the same level with my src file and  added to class folder(library).

I have searched for solutions on the Internet for over a week and still got no progress. I am really interested in making my own game and I really need your help!!! And sorry for any untidiness since this is my first time asking on stack overflow and I still don’t get used to it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Examine your .jar file’s contents.  Does it have a `/text/mods.png` entry in it?

Comment: @VGR yes I opened it up by 7-zip and saw that there is a texture folder and png in it. Res disappeared though

Comment: It's likely the `static` method is getting the wrong class loader. Remove all references to `static` and  change `ImageLoader.class.getResource(path)` to `this.getClass().getResource(path)`.